# Embed phpBB within Wordpress?

Tags: forum

Using Wordpress v3.1.1 to setup a new CMS.
BBPress is not satisfactory, therefore I have chosen to use phpBB for the forum platform.

I have the [wordpress bones laid out](http://www.dekho.com.au/), and also settled on the boldy theme ([Site5](http://www.site5.com/wordpress-themes/)).
I would like to retain this theme for the Forum, so I need to find out how to embed a phpBB forum within Wordpress.

**How do you embed a phpBB forum within a Wordpress theme?**

*I had heard good things about WP-United, but their website has been down for over 3mths now, and the author has not responded to my emails.  Therefore I am concluding that the developer is retiring the plugin, and my confidence in it being futureproof is low.*

Comment: This Q is way global. If you make it more specific you'll more likely get a satisfying A.

Comment: edited to be more specific, but still includes background to why I want A.

Comment: I have asked a semi-related Q here: http://tinyurl.com/3tgup65 and here http://tinyurl.com/3p6fe6d

Answer (score 1):

There's no *real* embedding of another software into wordpress. If you want to visually embed it, then you'd have to take a look if and how phpBB uses templates and then add the same nav to the phpBB templates. The look and feel can be done via css. You'll have to

- a) add the same css IDs and classes to the phpBB template parts as you got in your wp templates or
- b) Make a new stylesheet for phpBB and asign the same style definitions you got in your wp stylesheets to the according phpBB html-elements.

Comment: You can kind of embed using this: http://darkircop.org/vvvi/
However, I think this will cause me further problems later on.  

I have been trying to get help on how to fiddle header templates in phpBB, but as they use php/menus it is prooving a bit beyond me.
http://tinyurl.com/3p6fe6d

Comment: Following the instructions on your link, it seems pretty straight forward: Install both, upload the plugin, add the links to the named plugin file and finito.